# Consulta SQL cruda devuelve datos de tablas

Tags: adonisjs, adonis-5

estoy haciendo una consulta a una tabla en una base de datos desde AdonisJs 5 y usando un método que usa una `rawQuery` me devuelve los datos deseados pero además los datos de cada campo de la tabla. Lo que yo necesito es simplemente los datos que hay en la tabla, no los atributos de cada campo, como puedo hacer para eliminar esos datos y solo quedarme con los de la consulta? No se que puedo intentar para eliminarlo ya que nunca me habia pasado esto.

Mi controlador con la consulta:

```
async clientes({ auth }) {
    const clientes = await Database.rawQuery("SELECT clientes.id, clientes.id_empresa, clientes.nombre, clientes.direccion, clientes.telefono, clientes.cuit, categorias.nombre as categoria, localidades.nombre as localidad, provincias.nombre as provincia, zonas.nombre as zona, tipos_contribuyentes.nombre as tipo_contribuyente FROM `clientes` LEFT JOIN `provincias` ON provincias.id=clientes.id_provincia LEFT JOIN `localidades` ON localidades.id=clientes.id_localidad LEFT JOIN `categorias` ON categorias.id=clientes.id_categoria LEFT JOIN `zonas` ON zonas.id=clientes.id_zona LEFT JOIN `tipos_contribuyentes` ON tipos_contribuyentes.id=clientes.id_contribuyente WHERE clientes.id_empresa=:id_empresa", {id_empresa: auth.user.empresa})
    return clientes
}
```

La respuesta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede apreciar, devuelve tanto los datos que pido en la consulta como los datos de los campos respectivamente. Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, gracias!!

Comment: Probaste la consulta en su phpmyadmin manualmente a ver si es la consulta?

Comment: Adonisjs tiene forma de [usar join en su query builder](https://docs.adonisjs.com/reference/database/query-builder#join). Creo que podrías lograrlo a través de relaciones también

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La salida que obtienes por medio del *raw query builder* tendría una estructura similar a esto:

```
[
  [
    {
      data recuperada
    },
    {
      posible mas data recuperada
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      .......................
    },
    .........................
    .........................
  ]
]
```

Que como notas es un array cuyo primer elemento es otro array de objeto(s), es este mismo el cual contiene la información recuperada de la o las tablas consultadas.

Entonces lo que puedes hacer es indicar el índice del elemento a recuperar y así sea esta la única información que viaje a tu vista:

```
const clientes = ...................................................

return clientes[0]
```

Lo cual ahora nos daría una estructura como la siguiente:

```
[
  {
    aquí hay datos
  },
  {
    si se recupera mas de una fila, entonces aquí habrá mas datos
  }
]
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Se me ocurrió después la solución aunque no sabía como aplicarla, asi que mil gracias!